# Meaning of statement about differential forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a complex algebraic surface (smooth and proper over $\mathbf{C}$) and let $D$ be a divisor on $S$. What does it mean for a meromorphic section of the sheaf $(\Omega^1_S)^{\otimes m}$ to be tangent to $D$? I don't know what this should mean...